# How does a JavaScript engine understand minified JavaScript scripts?

Tags: javascript, minify

Usually, if plaintext is compressed, there must be decompression routine. How does a JavaScript engine interpret minified compressed JavaScript scripts?

Does a JavaScript engine have built-in deminification algorithms?

Comment: minification just shortens variable names, eliminates as much whitespace as possible, takes out comments, etc... Anything to make the JS smaller, but still be syntactically valid. Basically it'd take `var this_is_a_really_long_useless_var_name=0;` and turn it into `var x=0;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to understand that there is a difference between minification and compression.

**1. Minification does not compress**

Minification is the process of reducing JavaScript to as few bytes as possible, by removing extra whitespace, changing variable names to shorter ones, etc. The encoding and characters of the file remain the same. Since a minified file doesn't actually change the encoding or functionality, nothing is needed to convert a file back since nothing really changed.

**2. Compression changes a file**

When you compress a file, say using [gzip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip), you are re-encoding the data of a file or stream into a different encoding that takes up less space. It is in this instance where a decompression routine is needed to translate the file back to its uncompressed state. When uncompressed, the file returns to its original state.

**3. Browsers use a combination of compression and minifcation to achieve as small of a bandwidth footprint as possible.**

What's great about minification and compression is that they *are* two separate processes that do two separate things, and they can be combined to deliver as small a file to the browser as possible. For example, the original [jQuery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) source right now is well over 200 KB, but through minifcation *and* delivering the file compressed, it only takes ~30 KB of bandwidth to deliver to the browser.

Answer (score 6):

It does not need to be decompressed; minified code is still JavaScript. It’s just harder for humans to read.

Answer (score 2):

Minified JavaScript code is still javascript. Think of it as removing the white space and renaming long variable to shorter variable.

Comment: so, basically, minification is not compression at all, when compared to compression algorithms like LZW or Huffman coding??

Comment: No it's not compression. It's simply stripping whitespace and renaming variables. Some tools have optimization as well, check Closure Compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Minified JavaScript is simply that same code, but abbreviated (e.g. var foobar = 2 may before var a=2;)

GZipped JavaScript files (and other static files) are genuinely compressed, and do indeed get decompressed by the client machine before the engine uses them.

The browser will identify to the server that it can access zipped content by a header similar to

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate